# Both static background and static header in conflict

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a static header that stays floating at the top. the background is also static,

somehow the background seems to hide the header and show in front of the header.

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
#page-background {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#content {position:relative; z-index:1; padding:10px;}


#mainframe{
    color: #FFF;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    }
#right{
    float:right;
    width: 479px;
    }
#left{
    float:left;
}
#footer{
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 50px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-top-color: #F00;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: url(images/bartrans.png);
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#txt{
    clear: both;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
    }
    #header {
    position:fixed;
top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px dotted #F00;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#headercontent {
    background-color: #F00;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  


    }
</style>

<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
html {overflow-y:hidden;}
body {overflow-y:auto;}
#page-background {position:absolute; z-index:-1;}
#content {position:static;padding:10px;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="headercontent">
<img src="images/fmenewlogo.png" width="327" height="133" />

</div>



</div>
<div id="page-background"><img src="images/Music_Equalizer_by_Merlin2525.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Smile"></div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `z-index: 10;` to the `#header` css rule and `z-index: 0;` to `#page-background` rule. You can see my Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EKJxh/).

Comment: though now I don't know haw to add the content which stays now also behind the background i tried to add a div with z-index 10 but did not work @circle-B

Comment: You need to make sure that the position is set to relative, absolute or static for z-index to work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't set the `#page-background` to `position: fixed;`

You can set the background-image or whatever you are using to `background-attachment: fixed;`, so then, when you set the header element to `position: fixed;` they won't clash. I wish we had more to work from, like a link to the page you are working on.

It's hard to create a test environment for you without the assets you are using.

Also, another thing I see as an issue is that you are using a DIV element to set the background image.

Apply the background image to the BODY element and you won't have to worry about any of this.

See a JSFiddle here to see the code I was working with: http://jsfiddle.net/mikelegacy/5P7TN/

Notice that I have removed the #page-background ID and used the BODY element to apply the background image. You shouldn't apply full page background images with DIVs, that's not semantic.

Here is the code exactly how you should copy/paste it in your editor:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
     height:200%; 
     margin:0; 
     padding:0;}
body { 
    background-image: url(images/Music_Equalizer_by_Merlin2525.png); 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-position: 0 0; 
    background-repeat: repeat; }
#content {
    position:relative; 
    z-index:1; 
    padding:10px;}


#mainframe{
    color: #FFF;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    }
#right{
    float:right;
    width: 479px;
    }
#left{
    float:left;
}
#footer{
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 50px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-top-color: #F00;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-image: url(images/bartrans.png);
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#txt{
    clear: both;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    }
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#FFF;
    }
    #header {
    position:fixed;
top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px dotted #F00;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#headercontent {
    background-color: #F00;
    width: 900px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  


    }
</style>

<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
html {overflow-y:hidden;}
body {overflow-y:auto;}
#page-background {position:absolute; z-index:-1;}
#content {position:static;padding:10px;}
</style>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="headercontent">
    <img src="images/fmenewlogo.png" width="327" height="133" />

    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
```

​Here is that article for full screen background images: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Some of the methods here use and IMG tag to set the background image. Not exactly semantic, but it's a hack for older browsers. If you could, I would recommend just using `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Thank you, If you say doing it this way I will try this and work on this.

Comment: Yes, this is the semantic way of doing it. You can run into many problems, such as this one when you are doing the way you had it before. You never would have had to ask this question had just set a background image on the BODY element, and not on a DIV.

Comment: Just tried it and your version does not auto fit the background image to the screen.

Comment: Just add this: "background-size: cover;" this is a CSS3 property to stretch the background image. If you are supporting IE7 or 8, this may not be the best solution for you. I added a link in the original answer to an article talking about perfect full page background images.